# Selenium C# creating new web element and getting response back

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a new element and trying to get the response back which should be a url but I am not sure how to get the response back from the new element. Any suggestions would be great.

```
public void Setup()
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\");
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.target.com");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        string execu = "var document = window.document;"+
        "var head = window.getElementByTagName(\"head\");"+
        "var script = window.createElement(\"script\");" +
        "script.setAttribute(\"type\", \"text/javascript\");" +
        "script.setAttribute(\"src\", \"https://go.playerzero.ai/record/6274691b00fbad01561df689\");"+
        "head.appendChild(script);";
        try
        {
            js.ExecuteScript(execu);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a `return` statement to your javascript string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your script to return the `src`:

This is a working example using `.NET6`, `Selenium.WebDriver 4.3.0`, `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.5300`

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

const string Url = @"https://www.target.com";

using var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);

var script = @"let script = document.createElement('script');
              script.type = 'text/javascript';
              script.src = 'https://go.playerzero.ai/record/6274691b00fbad01561df689';
              document.head.appendChild(script);
              return script.src;";

var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver; 
var src = js.ExecuteScript(script).ToString();

Console.WriteLine(src);
```

Comment: It looks good but it is fighting me on the var src = js.ExecuteScript(script)                      

  Stack Trace: 
WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
WebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
Tests.Setup() line 26

Comment: I used Net6 and the latest selenium version and worked in my end

Comment: @elyk17 Take a look at the updated post

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for you help. I have been stuck for quite a while.